# Как избавиться от лишней записи в таблице при ее генерации

Tags: php, html, foreach

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно избавиться от лишних записей в таблице при ее генерации.

Таблица:
[image]
PHP генерация:

```
foreach ($response['data']['Stat'] as $data)
{
    echo '
       <tr>
        <td>'.$data['Phrase'].'</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">'.$data['StatDate'].'</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">'.$data['Shows'].'</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">'.$data['Clicks'].'</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"> - </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">'.$data['Sum'].'</td>
       </tr>';
}
```

JSON сообщение вида:

```
{
    "data": 
    {
        "EndDate": "2014-03-09",
        "Stat": 
        [
            {
                "ClicksSearch": 1,
                "SumSearch": 60.06,
                "ClicksContext": 0,
                "PhraseID": 1681871754,
                "StatDate": "2014-03-03",
                "ShowsContext": 0,
                "Sum": 60.06,
                "BannerID": 220564133,
                "Clicks": 1,
                "Shows": 3,
                "Phrase": "участки по ярославке",
                "SumContext": 0,
                "ShowsSearch": 3
            },

            {
                "ClicksSearch": 2,
                "SumSearch": 165.79,
                "ClicksContext": 0,
                "PhraseID": 1681871754,
                "StatDate": "2014-03-04",
                "ShowsContext": 348,
                "Sum": 165.79,
                "BannerID": 220564133,
                "Clicks": 2,
                "Shows": 373,
                "Phrase": "участки по ярославке",
                "SumContext": 0,
                "ShowsSearch": 25
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое:
Добавляйте фразы в конце итерации цикла в массив отработанных фраз.
А в начале цикла проверяйте, была ли использована фраза или нет.

```
$usedPhrases = array();
foreach ($response['data']['Stat'] as $data)
{
    echo '
       <tr>
        <td>'.(in_array($data['Phrase'], $usedPhrases) ? '' : $data['Phrase']).'</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">'.$data['StatDate'].'</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">'.$data['Shows'].'</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">'.$data['Clicks'].'</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"> - </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">'.$data['Sum'].'</td>
       </tr>';
    $usedPhrases[] = $data['Phrase'];
}
```

Comment: @VenZell ЧУМА!!!! Спасибо огромное :)

Answer (score 2):

Вариант посложнее, с объединением строк:

```
$phrasesCount = [];
foreach ($response['data']['Stat'] as $data) {
        isset($phrasesCount[$data['Phrase']])
                ? ++$phrasesCount[$data['Phrase']]
                : $phrasesCount[$data['Phrase']] = 1;
}

$rowCount = [];
foreach ($response['data']['Stat'] as $data)
{
    isset($rowCount[$data['Phrase']]) 
        ? ++$rowCount[$data['Phrase']] 
        : $rowCount[$data['Phrase']] = 1;

    echo '<tr>';
    if ($phrasesCount[$data['Phrase']] == 1) {
        echo '<td>'.$data['Phrase'].'</td>';
    } elseif ($rowCount[$data['Phrase']] == 1) {
        echo '<td rowspan="'.$phrasesCount[$data['Phrase']].'">'.$data['Phrase'].'</td>';
    }
    echo '
        <td style="text-align: center;">'.$data['StatDate'].'</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">'.$data['Shows'].'</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">'.$data['Clicks'].'</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"> - </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">'.$data['Sum'].'</td>
       </tr>';
}
```

Логика в том, чтобы предварительно посчитать количество повторяющихся строк, и потом сливать их с помощью rowspan.

Comment: @vanchester голосую ЗА! Спасибо :)

Comment: @Артёмыч, пожалуйста